# Set specific date and time in sp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to set a specific date range within a stored procedure, my start date should always read yesterdays date with the hours set at `23:00:00` so the full date and time stamp should read `2018-06-11 23:00:00` and my finish date should always read today's date with a time stamp on `22:59:59` so the full date and time stamp should read `2018-06-12 22:59:59`, can someone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Aside: As a rule, it's a bad idea to play with the end of a day rather than just checking for _less than_ the start of the next day. Is it really impossible for something to happen in the last second of a day or does your data only have one-second resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`:

```
SELECT
    Now = GETDATE(),
    ForcedYesterday = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(GETDATE() - 1),
        MONTH(GETDATE() - 1),
        DAY(GETDATE() - 1),
        23, -- Hour
        0, -- Minute
        0, -- Second
        0), -- Milliseconds
    ForcedToday = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
        YEAR(GETDATE()),
        MONTH(GETDATE()),
        DAY(GETDATE()),
        22, -- Hour
        59, -- Minute
        59, -- Second
        0) -- Milliseconds
```

Using `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    Now = GETDATE(),
    ForcedYesterday = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE() - 1) + CONVERT(DATETIME, '23:00:00.000'),
    ForcedToday = DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) + CONVERT(DATETIME, '22:59:59.000')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is string concatenation:

```
WITH Today(ISO8601) AS (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),126)) --create an ISO8601-string
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(ISO8601 + 'T23:00:00' AS DATETIME)) AS Yesterday11pm
       ,CAST(ISO8601 + 'T22:59:59' AS DATETIME) AS TodayEndOfday
FROM Today
```

The CTE will create an ISO8601 date string like `"2018-06-12"`. The query adds the time (with a `T` as delimiter) and casts this to `DATETIME`. Yesterday is achieved by adding *minus* 1 day.

### UPDATE

Speaking about addition of full days you can replace the `DATEADD` with a simple `-1`, but I would not recommend this approach:

```
WITH Today(ISO8601) AS (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),126)) --create an ISO8601-string
SELECT  CAST(ISO8601 + 'T23:00:00' AS DATETIME)-1 AS Yesterday11pm
       ,CAST(ISO8601 + 'T22:59:59' AS DATETIME) AS TodayEndOfday
FROM Today
```

If you dislike the CTE approach you can go without:

```
SELECT  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),126) + 'T23:00:00' AS DATETIME)-1 AS Yesterday11pm
       ,CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),126) + 'T22:59:59' AS DATETIME) AS TodayEndOfday
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option (if 2012+) is to append the desired time in the format string

**Example**

```
Select  Date1 = format(GetDate()-1,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:00:00')
       ,Date2 = format(GetDate()-0,'yyyy-MM-dd 22:59:59')
```

**Returns**

```
Date1                 Date2
2018-06-11 23:00:00   2018-06-12 22:59:59
```

---

**Please note:**  `Format()` has some great functionality, but is not known to be a performer.